# Filtering a list by selected type - react typescript

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, filter

I have a radio button with four choices:

1. All
2. Daily
3. Weekly
4. Monthly

If the user selects all, then all tasks should be displayed. If daily is selected, then only daily tasks should be displayed etc..

My Json looks something like this:

```
{
  "title": "Bang",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "DAILY",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "task": "A"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "task": "B"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "WEEKLY",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "task": "JAA"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "task": "BAA"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "task": "YAA"
        },
        {
          "id": "6",
          "task": "PAA"
        },
        {
          "id": "7",
          "task": "ZAA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "MONTHLY",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "8",
          "task": "DRAGON"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**json file import**

```
import content from "../../assets/json/example.json";
```

**I have a function that returns a list of tasks using map. (daily, weekly, monthly)**

```
  const filterTasks = (taskType: string) => {
    let tasks = content.tasks.map(task => {
      if (task.type === taskType) {
        console.log(task.list)
        return task.list
      }
    });
  };
```

**This is how I show all task atm**

```
 {content.tasks.map((task, i) => {
                return (
                  <div className="example">
                    {task.list.map(function(element, i) {
                      return (
                        <div key={i}>
                          <Task
                            taskName={element.task}
                            taskId={element.id}
                          />

                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
```

Any tips would be nice..

Comment: You can use 'useState' hook to get the selected value from radio buttons. Then based on that state value for radio input, you can apply filter method on array.

Comment: yes, that is how I am doing it right now, but is there a easier way to get all tasks in the same function